# How can I get the borderSize/s of a plane?

Tags: unity, c#

```
public Texture2D gridImage;
public GameObject floor;

    private int borderSize;

    private void Start()
    {


        GenerateGrid();
    }

    void GenerateGrid()
    {
        Color gridColor = Color.cyan;
        Color borderColor = Color.black;
        Collider floorCollider = floor.GetComponent<Collider>();
        MeshRenderer floorRenderer = floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        floorRenderer.material.mainTexture = gridImage;
        floorRenderer.material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2(floorCollider.bounds.size.x, floorCollider.bounds.size.z);
        floorRenderer.material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(.5f, .5f);

        Vector3 foorSize = new Vector3(floorCollider.bounds.size.x, floorCollider.bounds.size.z);
        for (int x = 0; x < gridImage.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridImage.height; y++)
            {
                if (x < borderSize || x > gridImage.width - borderSize || y < borderSize || y > gridImage.height - borderSize)
                {
                    gridImage.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(borderColor.r, borderColor.g, borderColor.b, 50));
                }
                else gridImage.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(gridColor.r, gridColor.g, gridColor.b, 50));
            }
            gridImage.Apply();
        }    
    }
```

In the end I want to create something like this on a 3D Plane UI :

[image: Plane grid]

Comment: Do you mean the Unity plane primitive? It's 10 units by 10 units by default, then scaled by whatever scale factors you've applied to it and its parents. If you have a different need, can you edit your question to elaborate?

Comment: Your question does not have enough detail. Is `floorCollider` the object you want the size of? Is `floorCollider.bounds.size` not giving you what you need?